# Rails SCSS Background Image Not Rendering

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome

I have a background image I'm putting on a div that is not loading to the page even though the path checks out. Here is what the inspector looks like:

[image]

when I move my mouse over the path to see the image, on hover instead of seeing the image like normal the browser shows the path:

`localhost:8080/app/public/app/assets/images/backgrounds/person-blur.png`

does this mean the image is not loading correctly? My page renders fine with no errors in the console, so why wont this image show?

strangely enough when i do a `background-color: red` on the same property it shows up just fine...

Comment: have you restarted the server ?

Comment: no actually ill try that

Comment: try and reload the browser @Adam

Comment: tried that, still does not show

Answer (score 0):

I guess that all you need is to set a size of the div.
Try to add styles:

```
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
```

Comment: there is already something in the div sorry should have shown that

Comment: you're right, when you hover the image in Chrome the background image should show. In you css file, do you use `asset-url('images/backgrounds/person-blur.png')` as the path?

Comment: let me try this again and write back in a second

Comment: hmm doesn't seem to like that path, i can an "invalid property value" showing up

Comment: yeah, sorry, it is a deprecation, does 
`background-image: image-url('images/backgrounds/person-blur.png')`
work for you?

Comment: it does not good try though I've been messing with those combinations for a while now

Comment: damn, what version of rails do you have? Did you try with different image files?

Comment: yes has nothing to do with the image, for whatever reason no image can render, using 4.2.6

Comment: I read your post again, what came into my eye is this:
`localhost:8080/app/public/app/assets/images/backgrounds/person-blur.png`
the `app/` is twice here, are you sure the directory structure is ok?